# Replace #N/A with blanks in vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm using a loop to update the values in one workbook from the values in another workbook using the following code:

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub DateFinder()
    Dim rw As Long, x As Range
    Dim extwbk As Workbook, twb As Workbook

    ' Turn off notifications
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set twb = ThisWorkbook
    Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test.xlsx")

    ' Refresh UsedRange (get rid of "Ghost" cells)
      Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

    With twb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

       For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
         .Cells(rw, "Q") = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, "G").Value2, 4, False)

       Next rw

    End With

   ' Close workbook
       extwbk.Close savechanges:=False

   ' Turn on screen updating
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   ' Message Box showing that process is complete.
       MsgBox "Done!"

   End Sub
```

Everything works fine but I want to change the code to replace the #N/A results with blanks. I've search the site and found the following solutions but none of them are working for me:

```
    .Cells(rw, "Q") = IfError(Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, "G").Value2, x, 4, False), "")
    .Cells(rw, "Q") = "=IFERROR(Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, "G").Value2, x, 4, False),"""",Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, "G").Value2, x, 4, False))"
    .Cells(rw, "Q") = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(.Cells(rw, "G").Value2, x, 4, False)),"""",(VLOOKUP(.Cells(rw, "G").Value2, x, 4, False)))
```

I get a compile error with all three solutions. If anyone could help me with the correct formula that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Matt, what specifically is the compile error pointing to? What is the error message?

Comment: Of the three attempts, the second two will definitely fail because you're mixing formula string literals with VBA object references which will not raise a "compile" error but will definitely raise a 1004 runtime error.

Comment: Dave, the error I received was on the line of code in my three attempts at trying to replace the #N/A that I provided at the bottom of my original post. The solution was provided below. Thanks.

Comment: CHeers. The second and third attempts were definitely and obviously wrong from my perspective, and LS_Dev's answer addresssed the first :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to qualify `IfError` as a member of the `Application` class, try:

```
.Cells(rw, "Q") = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, "G").Value2, 4, False), "")
```

Another alternative is to assign the result of `Application.VLookup` to a variant (otherwise, Type Mismatch will raise on the assignment), and then check for error. This is how you can use the [`IIF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/iif-function) and `IsError` functions to check for error & cast to empty string in case of error:

```
Dim val As Variant
val = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, "G").Value2, 4, False)
.Cells(rw, "Q") = IIF(IsError(val),vbNullString,val)
```

Comment: I don't think OP *is* getting it working. `Application` should be `WorksheetFunction`, no?

Comment: Yup, `Application.WorksheetFunction`!

Comment: Odd - if I try that, I get the "unable to get Vlookup property of WorksheetFunction class" error.

Comment: `Application.Vlookup` should be valid. The difference is that the `Application` version of `Vlookup` can return an error without raising it. The `Vlookup` as a member of the Worksheet class must raise the error.

Comment: 2010 and I don't have any extraordinary or unusual References active. The compile error that OP has is probably the `IfError` which your answer *should* solve.

Comment: Actually, I'm using Excel 2013 and it is working. That's how I know I'm getting #N/A for blank cells instead of an error. LS_dev, your solution worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the function with an `IfError`. However, in the future rather than using `vlookup`, I recommend Index-Match. You can read about it here:

https://www.deskbright.com/excel/using-index-match/

`Index/Match` is a combination of 2 functions that have a net result better and easier than `vlookup`.

Also, if the time comes where you need to transpose data, you would need to use `hlookup` instead of `vlookup`. Index Match takes care of everything for you.

Comment: You can link mutiple worksheets. Then paste special values. Or, you can use an indirect and concatenate some cells together containing filepaths. That way, everything can be updated.

Comment: I know. But you will get #N/A same way. How do you replace them with blank (that is OP question!!!)

Comment: Oh, I was a bit confused. SUrround it with an IfError. But in general, you should use index match.

Comment: Edited my response!

Comment: I use `OFFSET(MATCH(...)...)`, however I also use `VLOOKUP`. VLooup is simpler and may times it suffices.

Comment: The main problem with vlookup is that you cannot use it for horizontal datasets. Index-Match can be used.

Thankfully excel has many functions to do the same thing, and can achieve the same goal in many ways.

Comment: This doesn't appear to really answer the question. Index/Match doesn't avoid the #N/A value if match is not found (without additional efforts like `IfError`) and it's only a matter of opinion that Index/Match is superior to Vlookup. In many instances, Vlookup is perfectly adequate and straightforward. Further, your recommendation to use `IfError` has already been implemented by OP.

Comment: Jsleshem, David Zemens - I'm not sure I follow you. In the first attempt to correct I surrounded the function with Iferror but I got a compile error: Sub or Function not defined.    .Cells(rw, "Q") = IfError(Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, "G").Value2, x, 4, False), "")